# if I ran the android app locally fcm token is generated successfully but when app is downloaded from playstore fcm token is not being generated

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

When I build app and install it via android studio, FCM token is generated but when I upload the same app to playstore, FCM is not generated or is null.

I've tried to add this `-keep class com.google.firebase.** { *; }` to proguard but still FCM is not being generated.

Comment: have you added the signing details(SHA-1 or SHA-256) received from playstore to the project on firebase

Comment: Glad to help you. Kindly mark the answer as right if it helped you and also in future someone can be helped by this answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the signing details(SHA-1 or SHA-256) received from Playstore to the project on firebase.

Comment: In my case its not working any idea?

Comment: Hey @AleemMomin sorry for delayed response. Have you found any solution ?

Comment: Yes I got the solution it is happening due to proguard rules. I have added rule but forgot to mention firabse reciever class

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue by adding the SHA-1 from playstore to the firebase project